# MAMP - Apache showing source code HTML and PHP pages

Tags: php, html, apache, webserver, mamp

I am trying to install Apache on my Mac (OSX 10.8.2).

I am using MAMP, it runs, but whenever I try to view a page (html or php) other than the phpinfo.php, I only see the source code.

There are no errors in the log file.

I have also tried with the pre-installed webserver, same result.
Same for XAMP.

How can I get the server to interpret the logic instead of printing it?

Comment: including index.php ? the first page you see when you access localhost

Comment: That is why I hate these "pre-installed" webservers. What is different between the php script that works and the one that shows source code? Different directories?

Comment: Are you sure it's working correctly and you are not accessing the folder directly?  You should be going to http://127.0.0.1/FOLDER/FILE

Comment: let me get this straight: If you create a new file in your mamp/www or wamp/www folder, name it file.php and inside you write <?php echo "Sample Text"; ?> , then if you access in your browser: localhost/file.php you will see something the whole code instead of the text "Sample Text"?

Comment: What's "the phpinfo.php"? You only get PHP executed if you name the file "phpinfo.php"?

Comment: i think he is referring to a common test page that only has the phpinfo() function  http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: OP, it would be helpful if you code the code that isn't work.  Ideally putting it right into the same page that works using phpinfo, so canr educe environment/testing variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try typing instead of localhost 127.0.0.1
like 
127.0.0.1/index.php

Comment: it was a very simple matter of permission. thank u !!!!

Comment: @user1803531 - If so, how could this solve it??

Answer (score 4):

Educated guess. You've tried this code and it runs flawlessly:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now you've copied some PHP code that looks like this:

```
<?
foo();
bar();
?>
```

... and it's being ignored by the PHP interpreter. Please note the important difference: `<?php` vs `<?`.

If that's they case, you need to do one of these:

1. Replace your short open tags with `<?php`.
2. Enable [short open tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) either in `.htaccess` or your `php.ini` file. You'll find the path to `php.ini` in the outout of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: +1 for guessing. -1 to question.

Comment: thank u all, after following every option and fail.